# How to select a test template from command line

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I create in my firebase console a **Test Template**

Firebase -> Test Lab -> Templates

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/api-project-XXXXXX/testlab/templates?hl=en

With a template name *S7_API27_N5_API23*

Now I like to select this template by name in with the command line tool **gcloud** like :

(this work's) :

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
        --type robo \
        --app app/build/outputs/apk/productFlavor_Name/debug/My_Apk-debug.apk \
        --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait  \
        --timeout 90s
```

This is what I am looking for :

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
        --type robo \
        --app app/build/outputs/apk/productFlavor_Name/debug/My_Apk-debug.apk \
        --templatename S7_API27_N5_API23  \
        --timeout 90s
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to specify a named template from gcloud.  Please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for anything you would like to see added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have created a feature request ;-)

Comment: @Gugelhupf - could you link me to that feature request?